# Как получить контекст в адаптере SearchView

Tags: java, android, adapter

У меня есть адаптер, я хочу фильтровать результаты на основе данных из SharedPreferences, но для их получения мне нужен контекст, как мне  его получить?

Вот код:

```
public class ProblemNameFilter extends Filter {

    private final String SEARCH_DATA = "SEARCH_DATA";

    ProblemNameAdapter adapter;
    List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filterList;

    public ProblemNameFilter(List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filterList, ProblemNameAdapter adapter)
    {
        this.adapter=adapter;
        this.filterList=filterList;

    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();

        if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
        {
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filteredProblems = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0; i < filterList.size(); i++)
            {

                if((filterList.get(i).getProblemName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) || filterList.get(i).getProblemCode().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    filteredProblems.add(filterList.get(i));
                }
            }

            results.count = filteredProblems.size();
            results.values = filteredProblems;
        }else {
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;

        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        adapter.problems = (List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems>) results.values;

        //REFRESH
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте и запоминайте `Context` в адаптере, когда его создаете:

```
Context ctx;

public ProblemNameFilter(List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filterList,
     ProblemNameAdapter adapter, Context ctx)  {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.adapter=adapter;
        this.filterList=filterList;    
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло